# How to send data from the database to the front end

Tags: java, spring, jpa, dto

Tell me how to get all its data from the database correctly by login. I wrote a code that checks the presence of a given login in the database. Next, I need to return all related information with this login to the frontend. it can be his description, mail, phone number, second name.

authorization:

```
@PostMapping("login")
      public ResponseEntity<?> login(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequestDto requestDto) {
      
      try {
          String username = requestDto.getUsername();
          authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, requestDto.getPassword()));
          User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
          

          if (user == null) {
              throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User with username: " + username + " not found");
          }
          
          String token = jwtTokenProvider.createToken(username, user.getRoles());
          
        
          return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtUser(
                  token,
                  user.getId(),
                  user.getUsername(),
                  user.getSecondName(),
                  user.getPhone(),
                  user.getDescription(),
                  user.getEmail(),
                  user.getRoles())); 
          
      } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
          throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid username or password");
      }
}
```

to create a user object:

````
```
public class JwtUser implements UserDetails {
    

    private String token;
   
    private final Long id;
    
    private final String username;
    private  String secondName;
    
    private  String password;
        
    private  String phone;
    
    
    private  String description;
            
    private  String email;
            
    private  boolean active;
    
    private  Date lastPasswordResetDate;

    private final Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;
    

    
        public JwtUser(Long id, String username, String secondName, String password, String phone, String description,
                String email, boolean active, Date lastPasswordResetDate,
                Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
            
            this.id = id;
            this.username = username;
            this.secondName = secondName;
            this.password = password;
            this.phone = phone;
            this.description = description;
            this.email = email;
            this.active = active;
            this.lastPasswordResetDate = lastPasswordResetDate;
            this.authorities = authorities;
        }
        
        
        
        public JwtUser(String token, Long id, String username, String secondName,  String phone, String description,
                String email, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
            this.token=token;
            this.id = id;
            this.username = username;
            this.secondName = secondName;       
            this.phone = phone;
            this.description = description;
            this.email = email;     
            this.authorities = authorities;
        }
    
        public String getToken() {
            return token;
        }
    
        public void setToken(String token) {
            this.token = token;
        }
    
        @JsonIgnore 
        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }
    
        public String getSecondName() {
            return secondName;
        }
    
        public String getPhone() {
            return phone;
        }
    
        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }
    
        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }
    
        public boolean isActive() {
            return active;
        }
        @JsonIgnore
        public Date getLastPasswordResetDate() {
            return lastPasswordResetDate;
        }
    
        @Override
        public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
            
            return authorities;
        }
        @JsonIgnore
        @Override
        public String getPassword() {
            
            return password;
        }
    
        @Override
        public String getUsername() {
            
            return username;
        }
        @JsonIgnore
        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
            
            return true;
        }
        @JsonIgnore
        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
            
            return true;
        }
        @JsonIgnore
        @Override
        public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
            
            return true;
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled() {
            
            return true;
        }
    
    }
````

```
database:
```

````
    public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{
        
        User findByUsername(String name);
        
    
    }
```
````

the authorization code is incorrect, since the constructor that collects the object to send it to the frontend does not understand what values to set. How to create an object using an authorized login?

```
UPDATE:

  

    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [db/migration/V1__Init_DB.sql]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1037) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resource.classpath.ClassPathResource.getUrl(ClassPathResource.java:83) ~[flyway-core-7.7.3.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resource.classpath.ClassPathResource.getAbsolutePathOnDisk(ClassPathResource.java:72) ~[flyway-core-7.7.3.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.sqlscript.FlywaySqlScriptException.getMessage(FlywaySqlScriptException.java:81) ~[flyway-core-7.7.3.jar:na]
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:54) ~[logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:na]
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:60) ~[logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:na]
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:60) ~[logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:na]
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:60) ~[logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:na]
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:60) ~[logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:na]
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:60) ~[logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:na]
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:60) ~[logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:na]
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:60) ~[logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:na]
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent.<init>(LoggingEvent.java:119) ~[logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:na]
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Logger.java:419) ~[logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:na]
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus(Logger.java:383) ~[logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:na]
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.log(Logger.java:765) ~[logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:na]
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Slf4jLocationAwareLog.error(LogAdapter.java:433) ~[spring-jcl-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.reportFailure(SpringApplication.java:843) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:808) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:348) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
        at com.creamsa.springboot.SpringBootCreamsaApplication.main(SpringBootCreamsaApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.session.JdbcSessionConfiguration$SpringBootJdbcHttpSessionConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setTransactionManager' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$FlywayMigrateException: 
    Migration V1__Init_DB.sql failed
    --------------------------------
    SQL State  : 42601
    Error Code : 0
    Message    : ERROR: syntax error (approximate position: "create")
      Position: 77
    Location   : db/migration/V1__Init_DB.sql (D:\prog\Eclipse\spring-boot-app\target\classes\db\migration\V1__Init_DB.sql)
    Line       : 2
    Statement  : create table user_role
    (
       user_id int8 not null,
       roles varchar (255)
    )
    create table usr
    (
       id int8 generated by default as identity not null,
       created timestamp,
       updated timestamp,
       active boolean,
       seconde_name varchar (255),
       description varchar (2048),
       email varchar (50),
       password varchar (40),
       phone varchar (12),
       username varchar (40),
       primary key (id)
    )
    alter table if exists usr 
              add constraint UK_username unique (username) 
    
    alter table if exists usr 
              add constraint UK_email unique (email) 
    
    alter table if exists usr 
              add constraint UK_phone unique (phone) 
    
    
    alter table if exists user_role 
              add constraint FK_user_id_role foreign key (user_id) references usr
    
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:610)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:760)
         77 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$FlywayMigrateException: 
    Migration V1__Init_DB.sql failed
    --------------------------------
    SQL State  : 42601
    Error Code : 0
    Message    : ERROR: syntax error (approximate position: "create")
      Position: 77
    Location   : db/migration/V1__Init_DB.sql (D:\prog\Eclipse\spring-boot-app\target\classes\db\migration\V1__Init_DB.sql)
    Line       : 2
    Statement  : create table user_role
    (
       user_id int8 not null,
       roles varchar (255)
    )
    create table usr
    (
       id int8 generated by default as identity not null,
       created timestamp,
       updated timestamp,
       active boolean,
       seconde_name varchar (255),
       description varchar (2048),
       email varchar (50),
       password varchar (40),
       phone varchar (12),
       username varchar (40),
       primary key (id)
    )
    alter table if exists usr 
              add constraint UK_username unique (username) 
    
    alter table if exists usr 
              add constraint UK_email unique (email) 
    
    alter table if exists usr 
              add constraint UK_phone unique (phone) 
    
    
    alter table if exists user_role 
              add constraint FK_user_id_role foreign key (user_id) references usr
    
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.doMigrateGroup(DbMigrate.java:427)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.access$200(DbMigrate.java:56)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$3.call(DbMigrate.java:331)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.TransactionalExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalExecutionTemplate.java:66)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.applyMigrations(DbMigrate.java:328)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.migrateGroup(DbMigrate.java:291)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.access$100(DbMigrate.java:56)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$2.call(DbMigrate.java:195)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$2.call(DbMigrate.java:192)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.postgresql.PostgreSQLAdvisoryLockTemplate.execute(PostgreSQLAdvisoryLockTemplate.java:69)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.postgresql.PostgreSQLConnection.lock(PostgreSQLConnection.java:99)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.schemahistory.JdbcTableSchemaHistory.lock(JdbcTableSchemaHistory.java:141)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.migrateAll(DbMigrate.java:192)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.migrate(DbMigrate.java:152)
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:216)
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:165)
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:572)
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:165)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:66)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782)
         104 more
    
    Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
```

Comment: Can we see any error? It's hard to understand where is the problem here

Comment: @L_Cleo I need help getting the parameters when I log in . the login is associated with the parameters that are specified in the object JwtUser. What I have now returns one login

Comment: So is ResponseEntity not returning correctly the user?

Comment: @L_Cleo updated the post. please see the error

Comment: I can see that the problem here is related to flyway... are you intentionally integrating flyway?

Comment: @L_Cleo yes. update post

Comment: I think you're missing some flyway configuration... have a look at this link https://www.baeldung.com/database-migrations-with-flyway

Comment: @L_Cleo the error has changed, already good.
I'm a little extra prodigy, as there are a lot of symbols
The configurations seem to be worth everything

Comment: Happy to hear that :) I'll add it as an answer so people with the same error might see it

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned from the .properties file I can see that you're missing the flyway configuration. You might need to add it
For a detailed configuration you can have a look at

https://baeldung.com/database-migrations-with-flyway

Anyways to temporarily diasble flyway you can just add the property

```
spring.flyway.enabled=false
```